# AngularJS http-auth-interceptor and google cloud endpoints

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to use the [http-auth-interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) with google cloud endpoints javascript client? It looks like using the javascript client generated by cloud endpoints, when there is an error, say 401, the status code returned is still 200, but with a json object containing error code 401.

Comment: No, Just update the module to meet your requirements. It's straighforward

Comment: I think the http-auth-interceptor only intercepts responses to requests made with $http. The google cloud endpoints js client makes rpc calls that always returns 200. Is there a way to intercept these responses?